# Trying to change Chrome ExtensionInstallForcelist policy from "recommended" to "mandatory" on Mac

Tags: macos, google-chrome, plist

This works fine on Windows using regedit as described [here](https://technoresult.com/how-to-hide-remove-option-in-chrome-extensions-page/) but for some reason it just does not work the same on Mac.

I've been toiling at this for over 5 hours and still have not found a solution.

I have modified my com.chrome.Browser.plist to force install my extension, but under chrome://policy it is showing as **"recommended"** instead of **"mandatory"** (like on my Windows PC). Therefore it's not actually enforcing the policy.

I have in my com.chrome.Browser.plist:

```
<key>ExtensionInstallForcelist</key>
<array>
     <string>extensioncodehere</string>
</array>
```

And in chrome://policy it shows up as:

`ExtensionInstallForcelist | Value: extensioncodehere   Source: Platform   Applies to: Current user   Level: Recommended   Status: OK`

Windows regedit took me one minute, this has taken me forever... Does anyone know an efficient fix for this? I just need the level to be mandatory...

Comment: did you find a solution?